# Redux Form Wizard Form values get deleted?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I implemented a wizard form with four pages. When I change from page 1 to page 2 all the form values are deleted. Weirdly enough this does not happen for all other pages. Redux dev tools shows the state change like so

[image]

Frankly, I don't even now what the red crossed-out text means (is it deleted, overwritten?).

The code is pretty straight forward:

**Index.js**

```
class ConfiguratorForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.nextSection = this.nextSection.bind(this);
        this.previousSection = this.previousSection.bind(this)
        this.state = {
            section: 1
        }
    }

    nextSection() {
        this.setState({section: this.state.section + 1})
    }

    previousSection() {
        this.setState({section: this.state.section - 1})
    }

    onSubmit(values) {
        console.log(values);
        this.props.sendAnnonymousOrderRequest(
            values, 
            () => this.props.history.push('/services/order-request-success/'))
    }

    render() {
        const { section } = this.state;
        return(
            <ConfiguratorFormSection>
                <div>
                    {section === 1 && <WizardFormFirstSection onSubmit={this.nextSection}/>}
                    {section === 2 && <WizardFormSecondSection goBack={this.previousSection} onSubmit={this.nextSection}/>}
                    {section === 3 && <WizardFormThirdSection goBack={this.previousSection} onSubmit={this.nextSection}/>}
                    {section === 4 && <WizardFormFourthSection goBack={this.previousSection} onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}/>}
                </div>
            </ConfiguratorFormSection>
        )
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return bindActionCreators({
        sendAnnonymousOrderRequest,
    }, dispatch)
}

export default compose(
    connect(null, mapDispatchToProps),
    withRouter,
) (ConfiguratorForm)
```

**FirstSection.js**

```
class WizardFormFirstSection extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.initialize({
            employeeCount: 8,
            diet: "mixed",
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { handleSubmit} = this.props;
        return(
            <SectionFormBoundingForm shrink onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <H2 three>Konfiguriere deine Bestellanfrage.</H2>
                <section className="u-margin-y--medium">
                    <section className="">
                        <H3 three uppercase className="">Grundsätzliches</H3>
                        <Paragraph three formParagraph justified>Wähle eine Kategorie von Lebensmittel aus, die du erhalten möchtest.</Paragraph>
                        <InputOffset>
                            <ToggleLabel>
                                <Field name="diet" component="input" type="radio" value="vegetarian"/> 
                                <ToggleSpan />
                                Vegetarisch
                            </ToggleLabel>
                            <ToggleLabel>
                                <Field name="diet" component="input" type="radio" value="mixed"/> 
                                <ToggleSpan />
                                Gemischt (+ Fleisch)
                            </ToggleLabel>
                            <ToggleLabel>
                                <Field name="diet" component="input" type="radio" value="vegan"/> 
                                <ToggleSpan />
                                Vegan
                            </ToggleLabel>
                        </InputOffset>
                    </section>
                    <section>
                        <H3 three uppercase className="u-padding-t--medium">Anzahl der Mitarbeiter</H3>
                        <Paragraph formParagraph three justified>Die Anzahl der Mitarbeiter, die beliefert werden sollen, hilft uns, die Liefermenge zu berechnen.</Paragraph>
                        <InputOffset>
                            <Field
                                name="employeeCount"
                                component={renderRangeInput}
                                min="8"
                                max="50"
                                left
                                number
                                heading="Mitarbeiter"
                                maxText={<span>Du möchtest eine Bestellanfrage für 
                                mehr als 50 Mitarbeiter platzieren? Kontaktiere uns bitte persönlich.</span>}
                            />
                        </InputOffset>
                    </section>
                </section>
                <Button submit type="submit" className="u-margin-y--medium">Weiter</Button>
            </SectionFormBoundingForm>
        )
    }



}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'configuration-wizard',              // <------ same form name
    destroyOnUnmount: false,     // <------ preserve form data
  })(WizardFormFirstSection)
```

Can you guys help?
The name of the form 'configuration-wizard' ist 1000000% identical on all pages ...

Comment: I suppose, `index.js` `onSubmit` function will take you to the page where is supposed to display the data from `index.js` form?

Comment: exactly, it pretty similar to this example from the docs: https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.6/examples/wizard/

Comment: Can you try `this.props.history.replace` instead of `push` in `onSubmit` function of `index.js`?

Comment: the problem occurs way before the onSubmit function is executed. I can see the state being deleted (see screenshot) when I go from page 1 to page 2.

Comment: Can you possible make a prototype for this, maybe it'll be easier if you edit this [one](https://codesandbox.io/s/0Qzz3843). I guess section one & two are enough.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have fields with the same name in the different wizard?

Comment: 100% sure ... I even renamed all the fields ...

Comment: Alright - I did not actually showed the part that caused the problem - sorry guys! On the second section I initialise the form with only the values relevant to the second section - which obviously overwrote the values for the first section ...